# Get all DB names with a certain table and run a query against each result

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm trying to run a query against all databases that contain a certain table with pymysql in python. I'm creating a cursor and am able to get a result set back of all of the databases I want to run my query against. I'm having issues trying to pass those database names into my query.

I've tried both using `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` and `pymysql.cursors.Cursor` to store the results, but when I try to loop through the result rows and pass them to a placeholder in a `USE` statement or having query like `SELECT * from dbname.tablename` I get syntax errors where it is putting single quotes around the database name.

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

conn = pymysql.connect(host, username, password)

cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  sql_find_db = "SELECT distinct TABLE_SCHEMA FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_special_table'"
cur.execute(sql_find_db)
cur2 = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.Cursor)
for row in cur:
  db = row['TABLE_SCHEMA']
  cur2.execute("USE %s", db)
  sql_query = "SELECT * FROM some_table"
  result = cur2.execute(sql_query)
  print(result)
```

I would expect this to print the results of `SELECT * FROM db.some_table`, but instead I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''database_0'' at line 1")

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a placeholder for a database, table, or column name, you have to use normal string formatting. For instance, you can do it with an f-string:

```
cur2.execute(f"USE `{db}`")
```